# Can't run scripts on selected file using Nautilus-Actions contextual menu

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, nautilus

I wanted to move some of the Nautilus scripts, like print, edit as root, convert to pdf from the "Scripts" folder in the contextual menu (`~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`) to their own entry.

When I select a sample file and run the script "edit as root" from the `contextual menu>Scripts>Edit` as root entry, it works.

```
#!/bin/bash
path=$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
path=${path%?}
quoted="file://$path"
gksu gedit "$@"
```

When I create a `Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool` entry for the same exact script (same file, same location) and select the same exact sample file, it opens a *blank file*.

I've tried this with printing too.  Same result.  It has something to do with designating the file that is selected.  But that seems weird since I am running the same exact script, just via Nautilus-Actions.

How do I tell `Nautilus-Actions` to run the scripts, using the selected file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  I needed to have the `%f` flag in the `Parameters` field on the `Command` tab.  The `Example` field shows you what command will be launched based on the parameters you use (see `Legend` for a list of the parameters).  The `%f`  directed `Nautilus Actions` to issue the command after the path on the selected file.

Here is a picture: [image]

This works using the script in my question for `edit as root`.

To `Print`, it is really easy -- no script needed (and I couldn't get any of the scripts to work) -- all you need to do is put `lpr` in the `Path` on the `Command` tab and the parameter `%f`.  This issues the command `lpr /path_to_file`.

So the problem I was having appears to be (1) I didn't designate the path for the script to work on and (2) although the print scripts I was using are self-contained (they don't function with a path after them) they didn't seem to want to work with or without the `%f` parameter.  I still don't understand this.

Here are the entries that I use for my NA (in case others find them useful):

- (A) **Secure empty trash**: Path>`srm -lrz ~/.local/share/Trash/*/*`; Parameter>none (note: NA will move the part after srm to the Parameter)
- (B) **Print**:  Path>`lpr`;  Parameter>`%f`
- (C) **Edit as root**: Path>`/opt/Scripts/edit-as-root.sh`; Paramter>`%f`
- (D) **Convert to pdf**: Path>`convert`; Parameter>`%f %w.pdf`